# Basic authentication for the web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, basic-authentication

I'm having problems to set up the basic authentication for the web service.
I'm writing standard web service (not WCF) using .NET 4.0

In the web.config I have the following settings:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity impresionate="true" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

The web service has one method:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Returns currently logged in user.")]
public string WhoAmI()
{
    return "You are logged in as: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
}
```

The test server is virtual machine located on the same domain as my machine. When I access it, I don't get anything for the CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.

I also tried to access the web service using the soapUI. I entered my username, password and domain but I still can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IIS (inetmgr) you can find Authendication Method window.(WebService1->Properties->Directory Security->Authendication Controls->Edit Button)

You can choose Authendicated access. (Diggest,Basic,Integrated Authendication)
After that changing your method will work as you want.

Comment: From some strange reason, I couldn't set the basic authentication by editing web.config file. I could do it only from IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change `impresionate` to `impersonate`?